# Dart: cannot convert List<dynamic> to List<Map<String, dynamic>> despite cast

Tags: json, flutter, dart, types

I am trying to parse data from a Rest API inside a Dart/Flutter application. The JSON contains a field called `data` at the root, which contains a list of `Word`s. I want to get a `List<Word>` from this JSON. I already have the following code:

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    
List<Word> temp = jsonMap['data'] 
    .map((map) => map as Map<String, dynamic>)  
    .map((Map<String, dynamic> map) => Word.fromJson(map)).toList(); // map to List<Word>
```

`Word.fromJson` has the following signature:

```
Word.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
```

The final call to `map` gives the following error:

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'
```

From my understanding, the call to `map((map) => map as Map<String, dynamic>)` should convert the `List<dynamic>` to a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, so I am confused as to why I get the error.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: please add what you are getting in jsonString and also add Word class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If `data` is a List of words, you can "cast" to generic List and iterate each item to cast into a new `Word` object,

```
List<Word> temp = (jsonMap['data'] as List).map((itemWord) => Word.fromJson(itemWord)).toList();
```

The key is String, and data is Dynamic, if `jsonMap['data']` is a List on jsonString, it's not a `Map<String,dynamic>` and can not cast direct to map.

Sample of jsonString and convert:

```
final jsonString = ''' 
{
  "field": "titulo",
  "data": [{"teste":1},{"teste":2},{"teste":3},{"teste":4}]
}
''';

final jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    List<Word> temp = (jsonMap['data'] as List)
        .map((itemWord) => Word.fromJson(itemWord))
        .toList();
```

**Word Class**

```
class Word {
  int teste;

  Word({this.teste});

  Word.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    teste = json['teste'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['teste'] = this.teste;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Generated classs using **JSON to Dart**
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Answer (score 16):

If you want to convert a `List<dynamic>` to `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` as the title suggests, you should cast 2 times:

```dart
(jsonDecode(response.body)["data"] as List).map((e) => e as Map<String, dynamic>)?.toList();
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using strong mode I had to explicitly define the field type the ? was also not necessary.

Note the 'dynamic e'

```
(jsonDecode(response.body)["data"] as List).map((dynamic e) => e as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
```

Comment: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast